# How to disable auto format number in Google Speech to Text (GoogleSTT)

Tags: google-cloud-speech

When I speak numbers in Google STT, it automatically performs a format of the numbers, for example, the following numbers:

2609-4198 808
2609-4198-808
(26) 09419-8808

Is there any way for me to disable this auto-format?
I just want user numbers, no formatting.